# Mock KendoUI component using Jasmine

Tags: kendo-ui, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I have a kendo combobox.
In one of the method I am fetching value from the combobox.
Is it possible to mock the kendoComboBox using jasmine.

```
 var $categoryComboBox = $('#Category').data('kendoComboBox');
 var selectedCategory = categoryComboBox.dataItem($categoryComboBox.select());
```

My jasmine test case is something like

```
var combo = spyOn($.fn, "data").and.returnValue(dummyElement);
                        var selectedCat = spyOn($.fn, "select").and.returnValue("1");
                        var selectedItem = spyOn(combo, "dataItem").and.returnValue({ 'ID': '1', 'ClaimTypeCode': 'WW' });
```

I am not sure what should I specify as dummyElement for this to work.

Thanks

Comment: Any inputs for me to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't structured your JavaScript for unit testing. You should separate the DOM from the code, so you can test the code independently of a DOM.

Take a look at [KendoUI MVVM library](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/overview), as this allows you to set up a view model (which knows nothing about the DOM), bind it to the HTML elements and Kendo widgets, leaving you free to test the view model easily.

The way you have your JavaScript set up now is going to make it extremely hard to unit test. The only thing I can think of is to separate the code that gets the value from the Kendo widget from the code that does something with that value, and then test the latter, passing in the value you want to test. Still not really the right way to structure it, but it would work for now.

Comment: Thanks for your input, yes this is existing production code and i joined this project recently,the code uses extensive DOM manipulation using jquery, so it is very difficult for me to separate out unit testing, I am refactoring existing code now  and using Kendo MVVM for better structure

Comment: @sajeshNambiar Good luck with it. I'm in the same position, so know how you feel!